# MPU6050: Two sensors receiving same data

Tags: python, pi-2, sensor, streaming, mpu6050

I am using the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B to read in two MPU6050 sensors at the same time. I faced some initial problems in setting up everything but now I am able to read in data relatively fast.

My concern is that, both of my MPU6050 units are outputting roughly the same data. Is this supposed to happen or have I made a mistake while setting them up? To provide context I'm attaching a screenshot of my data and also a quick excel chart which shows the comparison.[image: Data from two MPU6050]

[image: Accelerometer comparison]

My question is: Is this behaviour normal? If not, then is there an issue with the hardware or something lacking in the code?

The code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Acquire data from two accelerometers
#and two gyroscope sensors

import smbus
import math             # Mathmatics
import time             # Time Module
import datetime
import numpy as np

#
# Define
#
# Slave address
DEV_ADDR1  =  0x68
DEV_ADDR2  =  0x69

# Device Address
# Register address
ACCEL_XOUT  =  0x3b
ACCEL_YOUT  =  0x3d
ACCEL_ZOUT  =  0x3f
TEMP_OUT  =  0x41
GYRO_XOUT  =  0x43
GYRO_YOUT  =  0x45
GYRO_ZOUT  =  0x47
PWR_MGMT_1  =  0x6b        # PWR_MGMT_1
PWR_MGMT_2  =  0x6c        # PWR_MGMT_2
ACCEL_CONFIG  =  0x1C     
GYRO_CONFIG  =  0x1B  

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

# Sleep released.
bus.write_byte_data(DEV_ADDR1, PWR_MGMT_1, 0)
bus.write_byte_data(DEV_ADDR2, PWR_MGMT_1, 0)

## GYROSENSOR SELF TEST
bus.write_byte_data(DEV_ADDR1, GYRO_CONFIG, 0b11100000) 
bus.write_byte_data(DEV_ADDR2, GYRO_CONFIG, 0b11100000)

## +/-2g
bus.write_byte_data(DEV_ADDR1, ACCEL_CONFIG, 0b00000000)
bus.write_byte_data(DEV_ADDR2, ACCEL_CONFIG, 0b00000000)

## +/-4g
##bus.write_byte_data(DEV_ADDR1, ACCEL_CONFIG, 0b00001000)
##bus.write_byte_data(DEV_ADDR2, ACCEL_CONFIG, 0b00001000)


#
# Sub function
#

# 1byte read sensor accel 1
def  read_byte(adr):
    return bus.read_byte_data(DEV_ADDR1, adr)
# 2byte read
def  read_word(adr):
    high = bus.read_byte_data(DEV_ADDR1 , adr)
    low = bus.read_byte_data (DEV_ADDR1 , adr+1)
    val = (high <<  8) + low
    return val
# Sensor data read
def  read_word_sensor(adr):
    val = read_word(adr)
    if (val >=  0x8000):          # Minus
        return  -(( 65535  - val) +  1 )
    else:                        # Plus
        return val

# 1byte read sensor accel 2
def  read_byte1(adr):
    return bus.read_byte_data(DEV_ADDR2, adr)
# 2byte read
def  read_word1(adr):
    high1 = bus.read_byte_data(DEV_ADDR2 , adr)
    low1 = bus.read_byte_data (DEV_ADDR2 , adr+1)
    val1 = (high1 <<  8) + low1
    return val1
# Sensor data read
def  read_word_sensor1(adr):
    val1 = read_word1(adr)
    if (val1 >=  0x8000):          # Minus
        return  -(( 65535  - val1) +  1 )
    else:                        # Plus
        return val1

nis = 1

# Get accel data sensor 0
def  get_accel_data_lsb():
    x = read_word_sensor(ACCEL_XOUT)
    y = read_word_sensor(ACCEL_YOUT)
    z = read_word_sensor(ACCEL_ZOUT)
    return [x, y, z]

# Get accel data scaled sensor 0
def  get_accel_data_g():
    x, y, z = get_accel_data_lsb()
    x = x /  16384.0
    y = y /  16384.0
    z = z /  16384.0
    return [x, y, z]

# Get gyro data sensor 0
def  get_gyro_data():
    gyro_x = read_word_sensor(GYRO_XOUT)
    gyro_y = read_word_sensor(GYRO_YOUT)
    gyro_z = read_word_sensor(GYRO_ZOUT)
    return [gyro_x, gyro_y, gyro_z]

## Get temperature sensor 0
#def  get_temp_data():
#    temp = read_word_sensor(TEMP_OUT)
#    return [temp]

# Get accel data sensor 1
def  get_accel_data_lsb1():
    xa = read_word_sensor1(ACCEL_XOUT)
    ya = read_word_sensor1(ACCEL_YOUT)
    za = read_word_sensor1(ACCEL_ZOUT)
    return [xa, ya, za]

# Get accel data scaled sensor 1
def  get_accel_data_g1():
    xa, ya, za = get_accel_data_lsb1()
    xa = xa /  16384.0
    ya = ya /  16384.0
    za = za /  16384.0
    return [xa, ya, za]

# Get gyro data sensor 1
def  get_gyro_data1():
    gyro_xa = read_word_sensor1(GYRO_XOUT)
    gyro_ya = read_word_sensor1(GYRO_YOUT)
    gyro_za = read_word_sensor1(GYRO_ZOUT)
    return [gyro_xa, gyro_ya, gyro_za]

## Get temperature sensor 1
#def  get_temp_data1():
#    temp1 = read_word_sensor1(TEMP_OUT)
#    return [temp1]



# (Calculation of the slope of the 1 axis) slope calculation for accel data
# If inclined only one axis can be calculated by this function.
## def  calc_slope_for_accel_1axis(x , y , z): # Radian
##    if x >1: x =1
##    elif x <  - 1: x =  - 1
##    slope_x = math.asin (x /  1 )
   # X-, when tilted Z axis fixed. Y-axis.
##    if y >  1: y =  1
##    elif y <  - 1: y =  - 1
##    slope_y = math.asin (y /  1 )
##    # X-, when inclined by a Y-axis fixed. Z-axis.
##    if z >  1: z =  1
##    elif z <  - 1: z =  - 1
##    slope_z = math.asin(z /  1 )
##    return [slope_x, slope_y, slope_z]


#####################################################################################
# Main function
#####################################################################################

f = open('/home/pi/projects/accelerometer/data/accel/22_03_17_carotide_A1.txt','w')
#f1 = open('/home/pi/projects/accelerometer/data/accel/22_03_17_carotide_B1.txt','w')

while 1:

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    timestamp1 = now.strftime("%H;%M;%S;%f")
    accel_x1, accel_y1, accel_z1 = get_accel_data_g()
    accel_x2, accel_y2, accel_z2 = get_accel_data_g1()
    gyro_x, gyro_y, gyro_z = get_gyro_data()
    gyro_xa, gyro_ya, gyro_za = get_gyro_data1()
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    timestamp2 = now.strftime("%H;%M;%S;%f")


#    temp = get_temp_data()
#    temp1 = get_temp_data1()


##    slope_x1, slope_y1, slope_z1 = calc_slope_for_accel_1axis (accel_x1, accel_y1, accel_z1)
##    slope_x1 = math.degrees(slope_x1)
##    slope_y1 = math.degrees(slope_y1)
##    slope_z1 = math.degrees (slope_z1)

##    slope_x2, slope_y2, slope_z2 = calc_slope_for_accel_1axis (accel_x2, accel_y2, accel_z2)
##    slope_x2 = math.degrees(slope_x2)
##    slope_y2 = math.degrees(slope_y2)
##    slope_z2 = math.degrees (slope_z2)

    data = nis, accel_x1, accel_y1, accel_z1

    value1 = "%6.5f" %accel_x1
    value2 = "%6.5f" %accel_y1
    value3 = "%6.5f" %accel_z1

    value4 = "%6.5f" %accel_x2
    value5 = "%6.5f" %accel_y2
    value6 = "%6.5f" %accel_z2

    outstring = str(timestamp1) + " ;" +  value1 + " ;" + value2 + " ;" + value3 + " ;" +  ("%5d" % gyro_x) + " ;" + ("%5d" % gyro_y) + " ;" + ("%5d" % gyro_z) + "\n"
#    outstring1 =str(timestamp2) + " ;" +  value4 + " ;" + value5 + " ;" + value6 + " ;" +  ("%5d" % gyro_xa) + " ;" + ("%5d" % gyro_ya) + " ;" + ("%5d" % gyro_za) + "\n"
#    outstring = str(timestamp) + " ;" +  value1 + " ;" + value2 + " ;" + value3 + " ;" +  ("%5d" % gyro_x) + " ;" + ("%5d" % gyro_y) + " ;" + ("%5d" % gyro_z) + " ;" + ("%5.2d" % temp) + "\n"
#    outstring1 =str(timestamp) + " ;" +  value4 + " ;" + value5 + " ;" + value6 + " ;" +  ("%5d" % gyro_xa) + " ;" + ("%5d" % gyro_ya) + " ;" + ("%5d" % gyro_za) + " ;" + temp1 + "\n"


#    print  'inclination [theta]',
#    print  'X:  %06.3f' % slope_x1,
#    print  'X:  %06.3f' % slope_x2,
#    print #newline.
    # print  'Y: %06.3f'  % slope_y1,
    # print  'Y: %06.3f'  % slope_y2,
    # print #newline.
#    print  'Z: %06.3f'  % slope_z1,
#    print  'Z: %06.3f'  % slope_z2,
#    print  'Z: %6.3f'  % accel_z1,
#    print  'Z: %6.3f'  % accel_z2,
#    print #newline.

    f.write(outstring+'\n')
#    f1.write(outstring1+'\n')
    nis = nis+1


# END
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, in your code you initialise your `bus` object to use port I2C1, and then use that for both your device calls.
Is this correct? Are both your sensors connected to the same I2C bus?

Secondly, your code would be easier to read and maintain if you combined your duplicate functions into single functions which accept `device_address` as a parameter.

Lastly, as you've pasted it, your code only outputs results from a single sensor. I assume that you ran this script a couple of times, commenting out and uncommenting the various `outstring` assignments to get the data you've posted?
If you didn't, then you're only plotting the output of the first sensor.

Comment: random driveby downvote without comment isn't helpful